# How assigning of base type object to parent type reference works?

Tags: java, reference

```
 class Home{
       void provideshelter(){
            //code
       }
       void Acessroom(){
            //code
       }
 }
 class KangVilla extends Home{
       void AutomaticGates(){
            //code
       }
       //now KangVilla have more methods than Home,clearly.
       public static void main(String[] args){
             Home H = new KangVilla();
             KangVilla k = (KangVilla) H;// i am having problem with these statements
       }
 }
```

**Question** I have read that at Compile time compiler will **only** check reference variable not the actual object.So when i say `Home H` it means compiler thought about **H** not `KangVilla` which is the original one.And it cares about the methods only which are accessible through reference `H` of type `Home` and these are **2** in this case,ok.But it allows the next statement which is

```
 KangVilla k = (KangVilla) H;
```

Now this is a simple logic that `k` can access more methods than `H` as it is of derived class type.So why compiler is not complaning on the basis that if `H` is converted to `k` then (not loosing 'H' in this conversion) it is possible through `k` to access more methods ( Home's + local to KangVilla) which are not possible to access through `H`?

so how compiler without seeing actual object and only seeing reference variable evaluate this?

Comment: If the cast is invalid, you will get an exception at runtime.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i am asking How compiler validate this?

Comment: It doesn't.  The runtime does.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ok,then in which case compiler complains?what is the function of compiler in this scenario,more specifically?

Comment: If `KangVilla` and `Home` were unrelated types, then the compiler would complain.

Comment: Downcasting tells the compiler "I know you can't validate that this is valid, but I know better than you do. If I'm wrong, then I accept to get a ClassCastException when running the program". The compiler always accepts that, except when it knows that it's completely impossible. For example, casting an Integer to a String will be rejected by the compiler, because there's no way an object can be an Integer and a String.

Comment: @JBNizet Problem is that we can do the cast in both way,i.e, base to derive and derive to base?so how these two things are possible?

Comment: Upcasting is legal, but useless. Using `Object o = (Object) string;` is the same as doing `Object o = string;`.

Comment: @JBNizet oh! like `double d = 3.34f` prints 3.3400001524578?

Comment: @JBNizet *implicit widening*?

Comment: That has nothing to do with upcasting. It's just that there is no precise double representation of 3.34. You can't represent an infinity of real numbers in 64 bits. Casting of primitive types and casting of objects don't have the same semantics.

Comment: @JBNizet but they are compareable

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not complain, because he cannot evaluate whether the statement is illegal during *design time*. It depends on the *actual* type of `h`:

If you would use something like this it will *work* during runtime:

```
   Home h = new KangVanilla(); //this is legal
   ... //other code
   KangVilla k = (KangVilla) h; //so this IS legal.
   k.AutomaticGates();
```

But this will throw a Cast-Exception:

```
 Home h = new Home(); //this is legal
 KangVilla k = (KangVilla) h; //but this isn't.
 k.Autom aticGates();
```

---

Real Type difference im talking about:

```
Home h = new Home();
System.out.println(h instanceof Home); //true;
System.out.println(h instanceof KangVanilla); //false;


Home h = new KangVanilla(); //this is a REAL KangVanilla, Casted up to Home.
System.out.println(h instanceof Home); //true;
System.out.println(h instanceof KangVanilla); //true - so THIS can be casted DOWN to a KangVanilla;
```

Comment: So the legality of casting is checked at runtime but why it is not included at compile time,i mean compiler knows that which class is inherited from which class so why it cannot check `KangVilla k = (KangVilla) h;` at compile time what is its benifit of leaving this till runtime?

Comment: @Bayant_singh Upcasting is ALWAYS allowed. But you can not cast DOWN, unless - as the example shows - the *real* type matches the Cast-Target-Type. Since the Compiler can't know, if `Home h` is holding a `Home` or a `KangVanilla` which extends home, he can not render the DownCast invalid for sure. If it's a `Home` - it fails. But if it's `KangVanialla` just upcasted to `Home` it works. Upcosting does NOT erase information from the instance. So a Downcast is possible again.

Comment: By **real** type you mean type of actual object?

Comment: So in your second case is there are two real objects are created?

Comment: @Bayant_singh no. An Instance always inherits the types of his parents - but a parent is not inheriting its child type. Real World Example: "Every Dog is a Animal (`dog extends animal`). But not Every Animal is a dog!". So, if the Animal you are refering to is a dog in reality - you can give it dogfood. If it is a cat, you cant...

Comment: one more problem is that if we do `Home h = new Room();` by defining a class Room but not including in inheritance tree,then compiler gives error this means it is checking what type of object we are creating so Why not these things are at compile time according to this example?

Comment: one more problem is that if we do Home h = new Room(); by defining a class Room but not including in inheritance tree,then compiler gives error this means it is checking what type of object we are creating so Why not these things are at compile time according to this example?